How can I include departure time in Google Flights search URLs using the q parameter?
I'm trying to generate Google Flights search URLs that include specific departure times using the q parameter with natural language queries.
For example, I can successfully create a URL that specifies the origin, destination, date, and other filters like this:
https://www.google.com/travel/flights?q=Flights%20to%20DTW%20from%20ATL%20on%202024-10-24%20oneway%20on%20Delta

This link works fine and applies the filters for one-way flights on Delta Airlines from Atlanta (ATL) to Detroit (DTW) on October 24, 2024.
The Problem
I want to include a departure time filter (e.g., flights departing between 6 AM and 8 AM) directly in the URL using the q parameter, but I haven't been able to get it to work. I've tried various phrasings and formats, but none seem to apply the departure time filter when the link is opened.
Attempts
I've tried the following variations in the query string:
Using different phrasings

departing between 6 AM and 8 AM
leaving between 6 AM and 8 AM
departure between 6 AM and 8 AM
departing after 6 AM before 8 AM
departure time 6 AM to 8 AM
departing at 6 AM
departing early morning
departing at 6:00 AM
departing at 0600

With different times (e.g., evening flights):

departure times between 9 PM and 10 PM
departure time between 9 PM and 10 PM
departure between 9 PM and 10 PM
departure time 9 PM - 10 PM
departure 9:00 PM – 10:00 PM

What Happens
When I open these URLs with the departure time included in the query, the page loads but none of the filters (like origin, destination, date, or airline) are applied.
However, as soon as I remove the departure time portion of the query, the other filters (such as one-way, nonstop, and airline) work perfectly. It seems like adding the departure time filter causes the entire URL query to be ignored.
My Question

Has anyone successfully included the departure time filter in a
Google Flights URL using the q parameter?
Is there a specific syntax or format that Google Flights recognizes
for departure times in the query string?
Alternatively, is there another way to construct the URL to include
the departure time filter?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
